# Matplotlib: Why doesn't my list comprehension stacked bar, plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to generate stacked bar plots through list comprehension rather than creating a dozen lines of individually created `ax.bar` code; yet my procedure below does not draw anything.

Here is a MWE:

```
stacked_bar = [0.03, 0.03, 0.14]
color_dict = {'cat1': '#8661C5',
              'cat2': '#0078D4',
              'cat3': '#2F2F2F'}

bar_position=0
stacked_bar_generator = [
                         ax1.bar(bar_position,
                                 np.sum(stacked_bar[:value+1]),
                                 color=key[1],  # color hex
                                 bottom=0,  # bottom is 0
                                 width=0.25)
                         for (key, value) in
                         zip(color_dict.items(), range(len(stacked_bar)))
                         ]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=60)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
stacked_bar_generator
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=60)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
stacked_bar = [0.03, 0.03, 0.14]
color_dict = {'cat1': '#8661C5',
              'cat2': '#0078D4',
              'cat3': '#2F2F2F'}

bar_position=0
stacked_bar_generator = [
                         ax1.bar(bar_position,
                                 stacked_bar[value],
                                 color=key[1],  # color hex
                                 bottom=np.sum(stacked_bar[:value]),  # bottom is 0
                                 width=0.25)
                         for (key, value) in
                         zip(color_dict.items(), range(len(stacked_bar)))
                         ]
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for multiple bars

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

stacked_bar = np.array([[0.03, 0.03, 0.14], [0.07, 0.04, 0.08]]).T
colors = ['#8661C5', '#0078D4', '#2F2F2F']

n_categories, n_labels = stacked_bar.shape
labels = range(n_labels)
categories = range(n_categories)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=60)


for c in range(n_categories):
    values = stacked_bar[c]
    color = colors[c]
    ax.bar(labels,
           values,
           color=color,
           bottom=np.sum(stacked_bar[:c, :], axis=0),
           width=0.25)

plt.show()
```

The reason why yours is failing is because you are not updating the bottom value for each bar plot (which should be set to the sum of the previous values).

I really think a simple for loop is more appropriate here, since your goal is not to build some special type of list, but to iterate over the categories and plot the bars. List comprehension just makes this seem overly confusing.

[Bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OleWE.png)

Comment: Thanks for your time and comment. I take your point, but in this case prefer the list comprehension application as there are many other plots that will be combined with the one I am working on.